# Heapify with ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I wrote this method to test my priority queue, which has as parameter an ArrayList and a Comparator:

```
@Test
  public void testPriorityQueue_ExtractMax() {
    PriorityQueue queue = new PriorityQueue(new IntegerComparator());
    Integer[] arrayExp={14, 9};
    queue.insert(16);
    queue.insert(9);
    queue.insert(14);
    queue.extractMax();
    assertArrayEquals(arrayExp, queue.getArray().toArray());
  }
```

Now, if I execute it, it says that the first elements in my result is 9, but I has to be 14 (the new root of my queue). These are the methods **extract max** and **heapify**. How can I solve it?

```
public void heapify(int index) {
    int largest = index;
    int leftIndex = 2 * index + 1;
    int rightIndex = 2 * index + 2;

    if (leftIndex < queue.size() && c.compare(queue.get(index), (queue.get(leftIndex))) < 0)
      largest = leftIndex;

    if (rightIndex < queue.size() && c.compare(queue.get(largest), queue.get(rightIndex)) < 0)
      largest = rightIndex;

    if (largest != index) {
      swap(index, largest);
      heapify(largest);
    }
  }

  public T extractMax() {
    if (queue.size() == 0) return null;

    T min = queue.get(0);
    queue.remove(0);
    queue.set(0, queue.get(queue.size() - 1));
    heapify(0);
    return min;
  }
```

This is the IntegerComparator:

```
public class IntegerComparator implements Comparator<Integer>{
  @Override
  public int compare(Integer l1, Integer l2) {
    int result = l1.compareTo(l2);
    if(result != 0)
      return result;
    return -1;
   }
}
```

EDIT_2: This is my insert method, can it be the problem:

```
public void insert(T elem) {
    int i = queue.size();
    int parentIndex = (i - 1) / 2;
    while (i > 0 && c.compare(elem, queue.get(parentIndex)) == 1) {
      queue.set(i, queue.get(parentIndex));
      i = parentIndex;
      parentIndex = (i - 1) / 2;
    }
    queue.add(i, elem);
  }
```

Comment: It depends on how the `IntegerComparator` is sorting the elements (min heap or max heap). Check how it is implemented.

Comment: I added it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a suggestion, consider adding an unused element at index 0 so that accessing the parents/children of each node is more intuitive.

**Example**:

Consider the heap `heap = [-1, 6, 4, 5, 2, 1, 4, 3]` where the root is defined as `heap[1]`, and the data for the heap is located from `index = 1` to the heap's size.

To access the children of a node at `index`, it is intuitive to say that the left child is defined as `heap[2 * index]` and the right child is defined as `heap[2 * index + 1]`. Similarly, to access the parent node of a node at `index`, one can use int truncation to access parents:

```
int parentInd = (int)(index/2);
T parent = heap[parentInd];
```

**Solution**:

As raul1ro has pointed out, you are losing the data from index 0 that you were not intending to remove.

In `extractMax()`:

```
T min = queue.get(0);
queue.remove(0);
queue.set(0, queue.get(queue.size() - 1));
```

should be:

```
T min = queue.get(0); //Get min
T temp = queue.get(queue.size() - 1); //Get the last element in heap as temp
queue.remove(queue.size - 1); //Remove the last element
queue.set(0, temp); //Set the root to the temp value so that you can heapify
```

This will make it so that you only lose 1 element when you `extractMax()`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please see my edit for an alternate method, otherwise raul1ro's solution will do just fine!

Comment: I think the problem is given by the insert method. Can you check it please?

Comment: Please upload the source code, so I may debug it. I will then walk you through the issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this `queue.remove(i);` automatically shift all elements, after index i, to left with one position.

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_remove.htm

And with `queue.set(0, queue.get(queue.size() - 1));` You just set value of last index from queue on index 0 and lose value from index 0, but it still remain on last position.

**After reading insert method**

At `queue.set(i, queue.get(parentIndex));` if `i = queue.size()` in first step, that mean index i don't exist in queue.

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: You can check if index i exist in queue and if not, use add. `if(i >= size) { 
queue.add(...) } else ...` P.S.: And recommend to fix extractMax()

Comment: `queue.add(i, obj);` - range of **i - [0,queue.size()]** and if at **i** index already exist something, will be shifted to right, one position, all elements from **i** to **queue.size()** .